# How to send a file to response a graphql query? (send a csv file from server to client)

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I wanna send a csv file in repose of graphql query.
I am using Apollo server and Apollo client and Reactjs.
(send a csv file from server to client)

can anybody give me an idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to send a CSV file as part of the response *from* the server, or are you trying to send a CSV file *to* the server?

Comment: first one. send a csv file from server to client

Comment: Any news about this question?

Answer (score 2):

YOU DO NOT HAVE MAKE AN EXPRESS (REST API) SERVER FOR THIS.  There are a number of ways in which you achieve this.

1. You can send and receive the file if  you base64 encode it.    On the client side to receive the file you will need to decode it from your JSON response. Then create an object to attach the object to in order to download it.
2. You can generate the csv server side and pass back a URI to the file.  Often this is a great use case for S3 or some other object storage.
3. You can convert the JSON formatted data into CSV client side.   Here's an article on the concept.   https://medium.com/@danny.pule/export-json-to-csv-file-using-javascript-a0b7bc5b00d2

If you have a large dataset ,  I'd recommend option 2.   If you don't have access to object storage then 3 would be best for download.

Answer (score 1):

the Graphql responses JSON format only if you like to download files in the front end 
you can implement another app like express to upload and download files from/to it.

Comment: This is misleading.  JSON is only the transport format.   Please don't tell people this. You can send and receive CSV if it is base64 encoded or stringify() .  Simply parse the data on the other end.